# ResultSet.getRow() displays row number 0 instead of x

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

We recently upgraded the Oracle JDBC driver from ojdbc5 (version 11gr2) to ojdbc8 (21.3.0.0) and we noticed a different behavior that we cannot explain.

```java
boolean stillDataToProcess = true;
int bufferSize = 20000;

while (stillDataToProcess) {
    ResultSet rs = getData();

    for (int i=0; i< bufferSize; i++) {
        if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
            // some stuff
        } else {
            stillDataToProcess = false
            break;
        }
    }

    log.info("row number : " + rs.getRow());

    // some stuff
}
```

**logs before upgrade**

```
row number : 20000
row number : 40000
row number : 60000
row number : 80000
row number : 100000
row number : 120000
row number : 124851
```

**logs after upgrade**

```
row number : 20000
row number : 40000
row number : 60000
row number : 80000
row number : 100000
row number : 120000
row number : 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JavaDoc for `ResultSet.getRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow--) says the following about the value this method returns:

> the current row number; 0 if there is no current row

Once `rs.next()` has been called and returns `false,` arguably there is no current row any more, because you've gone off the end of the collection of rows in the result set. So as far as I can see, 0 is the correct value to return in this situation.

Why the old version of the JDBC driver returned the row number of the last row when the result set was exhausted I can't say.  I had a look for a changelog for this driver, but I couldn't easily find one.

It's unfortunate that you've lost a convenient way to get a count of the number of rows processed.  It's still possible to determine this count in some other way, but it'll just require a little more work on your side.